# Exit out of a CPropertySheet Wizard

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a C++ application that is a Wizard.  During the application it detects if certain hardware is installed.  If it is not, it pops up a AFXMessage that asks if the user wants to retry or quit.  I have the retry part working but can not figure out to just exit out of the application.  I can have it go to the finish page, but I need it to just quit the application.

The class checks for the hardware in the OnSetActiveDelayed call.  If I do a QueryClose call it returns back to the base class but does not exit.  Should I have it call OnQueryCancel instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fkt014%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Even though CPropertySheet is not derived from CDialog, managing a
>   CPropertySheet object is like managing a CDialog object

To quit the wizard, just call the property sheet `EndDialog()` function, like

```
m_pPropertySheet->EndDialog(IDCANCEL);
```

where `m_pPropertySheet` is a pointer to your CPropertySheet derived class instance.